# Application of Lehmann–Scheffé theorem in a sample with normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

> Let $Y_{1},Y_{2},\ldots,Y_{n}\sim N(0,\sigma^{2})$. Prove that $T(Y)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}$ is the MVUE for $\sigma^{2}$.

**My approach:**  I need to prove that $T(Y)$ is the MVUE for $\sigma^{2}$, so I need to show that:

1. $T(Y)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\sigma^{2}$.
2. $T(Y)$ is a complete statistic.
   Therefore, by the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem we can conclude that $T(Y)$ is the MVUE for $\sigma^{2}$.

Since that $$L(\sigma^{2})=\underbrace{\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma^{2}} \sqrt{2\pi}}\right)^{n}}_{=h(\mathbf{y})}\underbrace{\exp \left\{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2} \right\}\cdot \mathbf{1}_{\{x\in \mathbb{R}\}}(x_{i})}_{=g[T(\mathbf{y});\sigma^{2}]}$$
so by the Factorization's theorem we can conclude that $T(Y)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Now, for to prove that I need to show that: For all measurable function $g$ and for all $\sigma^{2}$ we have $$\mathbb{E}_{\sigma^{2}}g(T)=0 \implies \mathbb{P}_{\sigma^{2}}[g(T)=0]=1$$

*But how can I prove that part? On the other hand, how would you use Rao-Blackwell's theorem to prove this result?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that Gaussian distribution belongs to the [exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) thus $T$ is not only Sufficient but Complete (and minimal) too.

To use Lehmann Scheffé lemma you have only to show that your estimator is unbiased for the variance:

$$\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{1}{n} n\mathbb{E}[Y_1^2]=\sigma^2$$

that's all

Comment: Thanks @tommik. I continually learn from her kind responses.